Как вращать метку в YandexMapsMobile, Swift?
Есть метод создания метки.
При вращении камеры она, не вращается, есть возможность как то отследить вращение карты или вращать метку? В документации не нашел способ реализации.
    Task.init {
            let point = YMKPoint(latitude: model.latitude, longitude: model.longitude)
            let viewPlacemark = self.mapView.mapWindow.map.mapObjects.addPlacemark(with: point)
            viewPlacemark.setIconWith(
                self.imageMark,
                style: YMKIconStyle(
                    anchor: CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 1) as NSValue,
                    rotationType: YMKRotationType.rotate.rawValue as NSNumber,
                    zIndex: 0,
                    flat: true,
                    visible: true,
                    scale: 0.5,
                    tappableArea: nil
                ))
        }



За вращение отвечает направление свойства, но оно не работает через setIconWith. Нужно использовать метод useCompositeIcon():
viewPlacemark.direction = градус вращения
let compositeIcon = viewPlacemark.useCompositeIcon()
compositeIcon.setIconWithName(
   "pin",
   image: imageMark,
   style: {
      let iconStyle = YMKIconStyle()
      iconStyle.rotationType = 1
      return iconStyle
   }()
 )


Такое вращение должно работать штатно, что можно проверить в нашем демо-приложении. Для этого не нужно указывать flat и rotationType.
